# configure apache mod_rewrite to serve another landing page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a website with a structure similar to the following:

```
/  
-- /public/ 
      -- index.php
      -- login.php 
      -- contact.php
```

Normally on the user is not logged in then he gets redirected to login.php. 
So basically when the user types myWebSite.com/ he gets redirected to the index page which redirects him to the login page.

I have added a temp landing page that I want the user redirected to in he does not specify a page in the URL.

**Examples:**

```
myWebSite.com/index.php --> index.php
myWebSite.com/login.php --> login.php
```

*However if he does not specify the page then he will be redirected to the new landing page, like so:*

```
myWebSite.com/ --> new landing page
myWebSite.com  --> new landing page
```

With the landing page added the structure is similar to the following:

```
/  
-- /public/ 
      -- index.php
      -- login.php 
      -- contact.php  
-- /landing/
      -- index.php // new landing page
```

I known that this can be done using the PHP in the index file. However it will be cleaner to do it in an .htaccss file and also the PHP file can be overwritten by automatic update.

I have tried to several times and failed:

```
Redirect 301 / /landing/index.php
----------------------------------------------
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) /landing/index.php$1
```

***Also is there a way to hide landing directory from the URL? even if that means renaming /landing/index.php to landing.php to avoid conflict between it and /index.php***

*Notes:*

**I have enabled and tested mod rewrite.**

Comment: what's the docroot in your config file for apache?

Comment: It should be /var/www/html since it's a CentOS operating system. I have tried the examples above with the document root but that did not work.